# Enumeration of different governmental structures?

Tags: government

Is there a book/site that encompasses classify and explains all different governmental structures and governance throughout space and time ?

The Greek city states, the Italian city states, Switzerland cantons, Rome republic, USA, Socialist, Fascists, Persian empire, Mongol empire, democracy, republic, plutocracy and so on and so forth.

Is there a rather complete classification somewhere..

Comment: You seem to be looking for a single authoritative list, and no such thing exists. It would be like asking for a list of all colours.

Comment: Looks like somebody found a book idea. Some similar ones might [exist](https://books.google.com/books/about/The_Many_Types_of_Government.html?id=QWVljwEACAAJ) already. Though, not exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 5):

Wikipedia is usually my first port of call for such questions.

[List of countries by system of government](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_system_of_government) classifies all currently-existing countries by system of government.  A similar list is given in the ever-reliable [CIA World Factbook](https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/fields/2128.html).

[List of forms of government](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_forms_of_government) gives information about the forms of government themselves.  For more detail, try [this article](https://www.scholastic.com/teachers/articles/teaching-content/forms-government/).

For previously-existing states and governments, Wikipedia appears to have a [separate list for each historical century](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Lists_of_sovereign_states_by_century) although the 12th to 18th centuries A.D. appear to be missing from the index and these lists may not be in a consistent format.  There are also some summary lists such as the [list of Classical Age states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Classical_Age_states) that may be useful if that is your particular area of interest.